# iPhone - removeObjectIdenticalTo behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, parsing, nsmutablearray

I'm trying this piece of code :

```
NSString* str1 = @"Toto";
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array];

[arr addObject:[NSNull null]];
[arr addObject:@"toto"];
[arr addObject:[NSNull null]];
[arr addObject:@"Toto"];
[arr addObject:[NSNull null]];
[arr addObject:str1];

NSLog(@"Tableau à %d elements : %@", [arr count], arr);

[arr removeObjectIdenticalTo:str1];

NSLog(@"Tableau à %d elements : %@", [arr count], arr);
```

Why does `removeObjectIdenticalTo:str1` do the same thing here than `removeObject:str1` or  `removeObjectIdenticalTo:@"Toto"`, as it is supposed to be based on the object address ?

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because the compiler is doing some optimizations based on the fact that you are dealing with string literals. The compiler is probably combining all instances of the string @"Toto" into a single object at a single memory address. This can be done because they are immutable.

This is why some people get confused into thinking that using the `==` operator to compare two strings is OK. It actually can work under just the right conditions but it must never be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting value in array then array is assigning address to all value, and when you are comparing your value with array's value then it checking all value. it is comparing according to value not with the address. so all value of Toto is removing .